# My kittens treat whiskas wet food as poop

Tags: cats, behavior, diet

I have two lovely kittens Moe and Joe. they are sister and brother.  I buy them [whiskas](https://www.zooplus.fr/shop/chats/boites_sachets_barquettes_chat/whiskas_boites_chat/sachets_whiskas_adulte/658254?utm_medium=google&utm_source=shopping&product_id=658254.17&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI--jdqeWI3QIV5TLTCh3ZIAjIEAQYASABEgIDCvD_BwE) brand for wet food and Purina for dry food.[image].

The funny part is that sometimes when they finish eating whiskas wet food their instinct kicks in and they act as if they took a poop and trying to cover it.

Should I change the food? Did you ever have this experience with your cats? Did you change the food?

Comment: Unrelated to their behavior, you should, in my personal opinion, probably change their food. Whiskas and many other popular brands contains sugar, which can have long term effects on your cats - e.g. weight problems, tooth decay or diabetes.

Comment: Whiskas and other common "supermarket" brands also contain a lot of indigestible plant matter (as obligate carnivores, cats aren't designed to get nutrients from corn). But their behavior is no commentary on what they think of their food, they're just trying to hide what's left from other animals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not about covering feces, your furballs actually try to hide uneaten food by burying it. That's a pretty normal behaviour for cats and mine also does it.

Further reading: [Why Do Cats Bury Food?](https://www.catbehaviorassociates.com/why-do-cats-bury-food/)

Comment: meow me thinks they were trying to tell me it tastes like s... lol Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: @HaniGotc: When my cats (who all have the food burying habit) start burying the food **before** eating, that's a sign they don't like the food. Coincidentally, they do that with Whiskas :) After some research, Whiskas is essentially the junkfood variant of cat food, compared to other brands.

Comment: I feel so bad lol I was feeding them whiskas sheesh. next month i am moving to Applaws or something similar. Right now i am feeding them purina hope it's not bad either sheesh